# Keybinds on xterm and emacs-nox

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, emacs-nox

I've looked on google, stack exchange, GNU emacs manual, xterm manual, etc. and still haven't found an answer that satisfies my problem(s).


**Problem:**

**Using Systems:** **Ubuntu 16.04**, **xterm**, **emacs-nox**

I want to bind the keys <kbd>Ctrl+i</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl+m</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl+[</kbd> and <kbd>Meta+Shift+o</kbd> to any command I want.

But the problem seems to be that all of said key sequences are bound to:

`Tab`, `Return`, `Escape`, and Control Code `ESC 0` respectively becuase that's just the way terminals work.


So how do I keep the functionality of the Tab, Return, and Escape whilst having said keybinds at my disposal?

Do I have to remap the keys in the terminal somehow? If so, how?

I will do anything to make this work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be fiddly then you can (mostly) do it. For instance, for `C-i` and `C-m`, add to your `.Xresources`:

```
XTerm*VT100.Translations: #override \
     Ctrl       <KeyPress> I: string("^[OJ") \n\
     Ctrl       <KeyPress> M: string("^[OK")
```

where `^[` needs to be replaced by the escape character, entered (in emacs) with `C-q ESC` (`C-q` runs `quoted-insert` which inserts the next character literally). The actual escape character can't be displayed in the browser, so I'm using the string `^[` to represent it, as that's how it's typically displayed. `\n\` is needed at the end of each line that is continued.

`^[OJ` and `^[OK` were chosen as these sequences seemed to be free. (You can determine which sequences are "free" by inspecting `input-decode-map` within Emacs, via `C-h v input-decode-map RET`. The map is effectively a "tree". The numerical values are the codes of the corresponding characters — for instance `O` is 79. You can determine the code of the letter `O` by evaluating `?O` etc.)

Load the `.Xresources` with `xrdb -load .Xresources` and restart your xterms.

In your `init.el` add:

```
(define-key key-translation-map (kbd "^[OJ") (whatever-you-want-1))
(define-key key-translation-map (kbd "^[OK") (whatever-you-want-2))
```

where again `^[` needs to be replaced by the escape character. Replace `(whatever-you-want-[12])` appropriately.

For some more details see:

https://kb.iu.edu/d/abko

https://superuser.com/questions/453993/xterm-key-translations

https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/xterm/xterm.1.en.html#Default_Key_Bindings

Comment: It's not working for me :/ A couple things are happening: 1) When I did `xrdb -load .Xresources` and restarted my xterm it like inverted my colors making the background white and text black (I haven't changed the default colors of the terminal); and made strings (in between " ") invisible within emacs. 2) When I did `(define-key key-translation-map (kbd "^[OJ") 'previous-line)` all emacs does is spit out the string `"^[OJ` in the buffer.

Comment: Update: The first issue seems to be unrelated; when I log out and log back in the terminal colors are back to normal.

Comment: Update: I think I understand what you meant: I tried `(define-key key-translation-map (kbd "^[OJ") (kbd "<f5>"))` and then `(global-set-key (kbd "<f5>") 'previous-line)` but it still spits out "`^[OJ`" in the buffer.

Comment: Update: Quick question: How do I inspect the `input-decode-map`. I apologize I'm definitely a noob.

Comment: Update: When I describe the key in emacs using `Ctrl-h k` for `Ctrl-i` the description is: `^ runs the command self-insert-command, which is an interactive
built-in function in 'C source code'.
It is bound to many ordinary text characters.` Not sure if this is a clue or not.

Comment: Last Update: So essentially `XTerm*VT100.Translations` is interpreting the input escape sequence and then spitting out the string of the given escape sequence. Should't we be translating the input escape sequence to another escape sequence and not a string? This is the conclusion I've come to.

Comment: Sorry for being too brief. I've slightly updated the answer.

Comment: Regarding the last two updates: yes we should be asking XTerm to translate the escape sequence to another escape sequence. Did you enter the character `^[` manually (with `C-q ESC`) or did you copy-paste the code? The actual Escape character can't be displayed in the browser, so copy-pasting `^[` will have the wrong result. (Again, sorry for not being clear enough.)

Comment: Ohh ok that makes total sense now!

Comment: This works very well. But what I'm not understanding is how you chose the sequence `^[OJ` and `^[OK`.  I'm looking through the `input-decode-map` and I can't really make any sense of it. How did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: Lastly, translating to `"<f5>"` doesn't seem like a very good idea to me, what would you translate it to if you were in my shoes?

Comment: The format of keymaps is described well in the [info manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Format-of-Keymaps.html). I picked `^[OJ` as the nested sequence 27 → 79 → 74 (the codes of `^[`, `O` and `J` respectively), was not present, unlike for instance 27 → 79 → 83 (corresponding to `<f4>`) and similarly for `^[OK`. You determine the numerical code corresponding to a character with `?{character}` and the character given the code with `(insert {number})` (or just look it up in an ASCII table).

Comment: Would, say, `"<f20>"`, `"<f21>"` work?

Comment: Ok I understand now. So can you just make up

Comment: Ok I understand now. So in my 27 -> 79 keymap the following are taken: `83, 82, 81, 69, 77, 70, 66, 67, 65, 68, 72`. Does this mean that I can translate to any other number I want except for these? And are an unlimited number of `"<f{x}>"` keys? I feel like I'm understanding everything, except the limits of what you can and can't do (i.e. the numbers to choose).

Comment: Yes, any number other than those taken could be used. Regarding the `"<>"` syntax, it seems after testing (but I can't easily find anything in the documentation), that you can use an arbitrary string (even `"<abcdefgh>"`) — so you could just  use the non-standard, but descriptive `"<control_i>"` etc. It appears to work and I don't think it would break anything.



(One issue that might come up in the future is if you start using a terminal emulator other than xterm — since they have different translation maps — but it's independent of the choice of the `"<>"` key names.)

Comment: Do you think there's a way for defining a translation that doesn't output a string? Like for example I have this: `Ctrl ~Meta ~Shift <KeyPress> A: string("^[JDA")` But every time I press it in the terminal it outputs the string `DA` Do you know of a way to prevent it from outputting that string?

Comment: Like for example why is `^C` outputted as a string to the terminal but `^A` is not?

Comment: With `"^[JDA"` I think that the issue is that this is interpreted by emacs as `M-j D A` and since `M-j` (unlike, say `M-o`, `C-x` or `C-c`) is not a prefix-key, it's immediately executed, presumably not allowing for any further translation etc.

Also, if you plan on using many more XTerm translations, I'd recommend going "deeper" (i.e. just use longer strings — I'm not sure if there's a maximum length on either the XTerm or the emacs side) rather than "wider" (using many different strings), as it's less likely to result in collisions with existing bindings.

Comment: Ok I didn't know that. But my fault I don't think I explained myself that well. So what I mean is that the binding `Ctrl ~Meta ~Shift <KeyPress> A: string("^[JDA")` works perfectly fine within emacs. But when I'm using that bind in the terminal (outside of emacs) it will spit out the string `DA`. And this poses an annoyance to me, because if I accidently press that keybind, it spits out that string, and then I have to delete it (note for the sake of brevity I have multiple translations like this, so it wouldn't just be this one bind).

Comment: Please move your conversation into chat.  Comments are not the right venue to have an extended conversation.

Comment: @Dan Where's the chat?

Comment: Cool @Dan. Was just about to have my problem fully solved, after three days of working on it.

Comment: Regarding interpreting the translated bindings in bash — I don't think there's any simple solution. You could try to use the `bind` bash command (e.g. `bind '"\eOJ": ""'` where `\e` is the escape character (yes, different conventions in different programs, for the same character, are annoying...) and `""` is deliberately the empty string — see the [info manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html) for details), but things are likely to start getting very brittle.

As for moving the conversation to chat, I'm not certain how to do that.

Comment: FWIW I've created a new chat room [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75839/keybinds-on-xterm-and-emacs-nox).

Comment: That works perfectly!